# Dismissable alert

Tags: html, twitter-bootstrap, button, alert, dismiss

I'm trying to get an alert to disappear when the "x" button is clicked, but there seems to be something missing that's keeping it from working, not sure what it is.

```
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
<button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss = "alert">x</button>
    You've done it!
</div>
```

Comment: Your question only makes sense when you're talking about bootstrap. Please be more precise in your questioning.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

for dismissible to work, you need to include `jQuery` and `bootstrap.js` in your document.

```
 <!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="utf-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1">
    <title>Bootstrap 101 Template</title>
    <link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
</head>
<body>
<div class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss = "alert">x</button>
    You've done it!
</div>
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
</body>
</html>
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/1.12.4/jquery.min.js"></script>
<script src="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://maxcdn.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.3.7/css/bootstrap.min.css">
<div style="margin-top: 50px" class="alert alert-success alert-dismissible">
    <button type = "button" class="close" data-dismiss = "alert">x</button>
    You've done it!
</div>
```

Comment: Thank you!  I was missing Jquery.