# Some bootstrap-features don't work in Angular, but do in regular HTML-file

Tags: angular, bootstrap-4

I'm just getting into Angular as well as Bootstrap. I build an Angular project, then added bootstrap to it after the fact (npm install bootstrap) and then tried various bootstrap-features on one of the html-pages. Some of them work, some don't.

The code in the answer to this question, for example: [Dismissable alert](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/43308367/dismissable-alert) . The alert is displayed, but when I click the X, it doesn't disappear. Strangely, if I access the exact same HTML-file directly in my browser, rather than via the served Angular-page, the feature works normally.

So where did I install something wrong? 
Here are some attempts I made, based on various hints off the internet:
Here's the relevant part of my angular.json:

```
    "styles": [
    "node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.js",
    //"node_modules/tether/dist/js/popper.js",
    "src/styles.scss",
    {
        "input": "./node_modules/bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css"
    }
    ],
```

My styles.css contains:

```
    @import url('https://unpkg.com/bootstrap@3.3.7/dist/css/bootstrap.min.css');
    @import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Comment: Bootstrap depends on jQuery functionality that often will not work correctly with angular due to the dynamic aspect of angular rendering. Just use ng-bootstrap as it is specifically designed to work angular.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

1. Import JavaScript files in the `scripts` property, not in the `styles` property.

```json
...
"scripts": [
  "../node_modules/jquery/dist/jquery.min.js",
  "../node_modules/bootstrap/dist/js/bootstrap.min.js"
]
...
```

2. Don't import a CSS file twice.

```css
@import "~bootstrap/dist/css/bootstrap.css";
```

Comment: Thanks, that worked! (except I removed the ../ before node_modules for it to point at the correct location)